# Visualize rendering time per pixel of scene?

Tags: rendering, render-passes

Is there a way to visualize how long each pixel took in terms of GPU computation time of the render?
e.g.something like a heatmap of computation.

I know it exists for other render engines but I can't find any info on something similar in Blender (and even doesn't know if it is relevant for the Cycles engine).

This would be helpful for identifying problematic shaders or optimizing the scene render time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is: the *Render Time* pass, available under *Scene > View Layer Properties > Passes > Data > Debug*. See [official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/passes.html).

You can view each of the render passes individually through the compositor, or by saving the render as an "OpenEXR Multilayer" file.

EDIT: This feature was [removed in version 3.0](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/109364) without an update to the documentation.

Comment: It seems perfect regarding the topic but unfortunately, I haven't been able to find it in the last version (3.5.1). Whatever I do and try, the Debug passes only contains "Sample Count" and no "Render Time". How do you enable it?

Comment: I confirm that I also tested 3.6 release candidate and that it does not show the Render time pass either.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the proposed answer is not accurate. From Blender 3.0+, this option has been removed as it only worked with CPU and the former model.

I just sent a ticket regarding the fact that it's not available anymore and it has been confirmed as an error in the documentation :
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/109364

As long as there is no new option, I'll keep the question open :)

EDIT : updated the answer according to ticket updates